# I'm getting an error when trying use the dart package odbc.dart

Tags: dart, odbc

I'm trying to use ODBC binding for Dart.

Within the package odbc.dart, I see the following import statement:

```
import "dart-ext:odbc_ext";
```

When running my app, I get the following error:

> GET dart-ext:odbc_ext net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
>   An error occurred loading file: dart-ext:odbc_ext

I don't see a github package 'dart-ext:odbc_ext. What am I not understanding?

Comment: Perhaps you need to compile something. I don't know about native extensions. Doesn't the package readme tell something about how to install it?